# HTTP 404 with Java + Maven + Jersey2 + Tomcat 8.5 and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to build a simple REST service in Java (JDK 1.8.0.121) with IntelliJ IDEA, Jersey v2.25.1, Maven and Tomcat v8.5.11.

I've written a simple class with a GET method in the package com.example

```
package com.example;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

<display-name>Simple Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>simple_rest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jersey2.version>2.25.1</jersey2.version>
    <jaxrs.version>2.0.1</jaxrs.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- JAX-RS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jersey 2.25.1 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've tried to run on my first pc and it works; but if I run the same code on my laptop it, when I visit http://localhost:8080/hello it returns an HTTP 404 error.

I got no compilation error and no errors message on the server console when I got the 404 error.

Do you have any idea of what is missing? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make sure you deployed it under the right webapp?  Also, restarting tomcat may help but I presume you have tried that already

Comment: I've deployed the application under the webapp folder of the tomcat folder. I've also tried to restart Tomcat but the problem still remains. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about add `@ApplicationPath` in other class? Here is the sample code.

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest-v1")
public class YourApplication extends Application {}
```

After that, maybe `localhost:8080/rest-v1/hello` can be accessible.

Comment: nice! But why was the app working on a different server tho?